# Attachment(PDF/DOC) Indexing and Searching on ElasticSearch in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have installed `elasticsearch` in my local pc. Also installed `mapper-attachments` and `kibana`.

I can index string data into a index and search. But when I trying to search text from PDF or docx in a folder :: Its not working. Its returning `null` or blank `array()`.

I searched on google and read the elastic documentation but Still I have nothing to resolve it. Would you guide me ? Here is my code ::

```
   $client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

    $doc_src = public_path()."/uploads/files/bower.pdf";
    $binary = fread(fopen($doc_src, "r"), filesize($doc_src));
    $doc_str = base64_encode($binary);

    $data_string =  'Welcome to Dhaka! Anwar is a gentleman!';


    //index data and assign by index "my_index"
    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'attachment',
        'id' => 'my_id',
        'body' => [
            'testField' => $data_string,
            'fileName' => $doc_src,
            'file' => $doc_str
        ]

    ];

    $response = $client->index($params);
    #print_r($response);

    //search data from the index "my_index"
    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'attachment',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    #'testField' => 'dhaka',
                    'file' => 'dhaka'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];

    $response = $client->search($params);
    print_r($response['hits']['hits']);
```

Bottom points :

```
1. when I tried to teach using `testField` from the `data_string` then its working nicely. 
2. When I tried to search from pdf file `doc_str` `=>` Its not working
```

I think I missed something big. Any helps is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think in this line **fread(fopen($doc_src, "r"), filesize($doc_src));** you are extracting data from document but may not be the documents text but metadata from .pdf file. II suggest to extract pdf text using libraries like pdfparser